# Как при изменении размера одного элемента, передвигать другие?

Tags: c#, wpf, form

Допустим у нас есть три кнопки, которые стоят в ряд, мы создаем якори(родительный контейнер: форма) на правую сторону, при растяжении формы через правую сторону, края кнопок заходят на другие кнопки.

Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы кнопки двигались(то-есть, чтобы края не заходили на кнопки, а эти кнопки просто перемещались вправо)

Хочу узнать как такое сделать на wpf и на winform. Одно для дела, другое для общего развития, но думаю там почти ничего не отличается.

Вот пример(Смотрим только на 3 groupBox'а):

Здесь groupBox'ы имеют якорь к правой стороне

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Увеличим размер формы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="_2DoList.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:_2DoList"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="547" Width="909" MinWidth="929" MinHeight="547">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TabControl Margin="0,29,0,0">
        <TabItem Header="Новый проект" Margin="-2,-2,-14,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <GroupBox Header="TODO" Margin="10,10,608,10" BorderBrush="Black" FontSize="24" Padding="0" FontFamily="Montserrat"/>
                <GroupBox Header="Review" Margin="312,10,309,10" BorderBrush="Black" FontSize="24" FontFamily="Montserrat"/>
                <GroupBox Header="Done" Margin="611,10,10,10" BorderBrush="Black" FontSize="24" FontFamily="Montserrat"/>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
    <ToolBar Height="29" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="White" Header="&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;">
        <Button Content="File" Height="24" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="47"/>
        <Button Content="Edit" Height="24" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="47"/>
    </ToolBar>
</Grid>
```

Я хочу чтобы стороны не заходили на другие элементы. Хочу чтобы эти элементы просто перемещались направо, а интервал между ними оставался тем же.

P.S В примере используется WPF

Comment: Нечего не понятно. Вы можете более приземленным языком объяснить? Желательно с разметкой и скринами проблемы.

Comment: WinForms: [1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/7k9fa71y%28v%3dvs.100%29), [2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/991eahec(v=vs.100)), [3](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/walkthrough-arranging-controls-on-windows-forms-using-a-tablelayoutpanel). И по ссылкам, по ссылкам! Еще: [4](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/automatic-scaling-in-windows-forms).

Comment: Там много чего отличается на самом деле, лучше выбрать одну платформу. Что касается примера, то может выложите код или покажете скриншот?

Comment: @defaultlocale Я обновил вопрос

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Я обновил вопрос

Comment: @Log1c0 Стало лучше, приложите еще XAML и уберите метку winforms.

Comment: @defaultlocale Для интерфейса я использую конструктор, а не пишу в XAML, так что если можно, не могли бы помоч сделать это средствами конструктора (Visual Studio) Обновил вопрос

Comment: @defaultlocale (И Вопрос не в тему, как убрать у toolbar эти иконки по бокам, но это не обязательно)

Comment: @Log1c0 `Для интерфейса я использую конструктор, а не пишу в XAML` - в этом вся ваша ошибка и дальше вы и будете получать подобные ошибки. Конструктор в студии очень тупой, он не умеет определять многое, например при добавление элемента и передвижения его в нижний угол он начнет делать отступы (`Margin`), а не устанавливать `HorizontalAlignment`/`VerticalAlignment` и от них уже отступы. Также дизайнер ставит четкие размеры элемента, четкие размеры сетки (а не относительные `3*`). `Margin` должен быть в пределах ~10-15, легкий отступ от края, не более. У вас `Margin="10,10,608,10"`, правильно?

Comment: Научитесь писать разметку XAML руками, она очень легкая, достаточно понять простые основы.

Comment: Впредь не смешивайте вместе вопросы по WinForms и WPF. Это слишком разные технологии. Задавайте два отдельных вопроса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, расположение элементов в WPF тема достаточно широкая. Можете почитать статью [Layout](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/layout) в MSDN для общего понимания.

Насколько я понял, Вам нужно, чтобы GroupBox-ы заполняли все пространство внутри при растягивании окна. Сейчас этого не происходит потому что размер каждого GroupBox-а определяется расстоянием до границ родителя (свойство Margin, которое Вы установили, растягивая элементы в дизайнере). При изменении размера окна на X пикселей, каждый элемент сдвигается на X, что и приводит к накладкам.

Расположение элементов зависит от родительского элемента, в данном случае это таблица (`Grid`). Поэтому для решения задачи можно воспользоваться свойствами таблицы, т.е. разнести группы по столбцам.

Для этого нужно:

- в дизайнере выбрать элемент `Grid` в который непосредственно вложены GroupBox-ы, найти у него свойство `ColumnDefinitions`, раскрыть его и добавить два столбца;
- переместить группы "Review" и "Done" во второй и третий столбец соответственно, для этого нужно заполнить свойство `Layout -> Column` (проставить значения 1 и 2 соответственно);
- уберите у всех групп свойство Margin.

После этого должен получиться примерно такой XAML:

```
<TabItem Header="Новый проект" Margin="-2,-2,-14,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <GroupBox Header="TODO" BorderBrush="Black" FontSize="24" Padding="0" FontFamily="Montserrat"/>
        <GroupBox Header="Review" BorderBrush="Black" FontSize="24" FontFamily="Montserrat" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <GroupBox Header="Done" BorderBrush="Black" FontSize="24" FontFamily="Montserrat" Grid.Column="2"/>
    </Grid>
</TabItem>
```

После этого группы будут равномерно растягиваться равномерно и каждая занимать треть родительской таблицы по ширине. Если нужно изменить пропорции, либо сделать один из столбцов фиксированным, поиграйтесь со свойствами [`ColumnDefinition`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.columndefinition?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> как убрать у toolbar эти иконки по бокам, но это не обязательно

Иконка слева называется grip (рукоятка?), она нужна в тех случаях когда панель можно перемещать. Спрятать ее можно через свойство `ToolBarTray.IsLocked`:

```
<ToolBar ToolBarTray.IsLocked="True" Height="29" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="White" Header="&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;">
```

Та, что справа, называется overflow (переполнение) и нужна тогда, когда пункты не влезают в панель. Ее тоже можно спрятать, но это несколько сложнее. Можете почитать варианты в вопросе на английском: [WPF ToolBar: how to remove grip and overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050953/wpf-toolbar-how-to-remove-grip-and-overflow)

Comment: Просто лучший, спасибо)

Comment: @Log1c0 Пожалуйста!